# How to apply a single condition on a sequence of multiple columns to create a single column in

Tags: r

I have a dataset which is similar to the following:

```
Age      Monday Tuesday Wednesday 
6-9        a     b        a
6-9        b     b        c
6-9              c        a
9-10       c     c        b
9-10       c     a        b
```

Using R, I want to a binary variable which represents whether the entire row contains "a" or not (1 as entire a and 0 as not) as the following:

```
Age      Monday Tuesday Wednesday  Entire a
6-9        a              a          1
6-9        b     b        c          0
6-9              c        a          0
9-10       c     c        b          0
9-10       a     a        a          1
```

Note: My data also contains missing values in the rows. The columns which are my interest are of "Factors". 
I use the following coding which however did not work:

```
L <- dataframe %>%
    select(Age,Monday:Wednesday) %>%
    mutate (Entire a = ifelse(c(Monday:Wednesday)=="a",1,0,na.rm=TRUE))
```

Comment: Be careful of your syntax. I'd generally recommend against using spaces in column names, but if you must, you have to use back ticks. ie `\`Entire a\` = `

Comment: your input data and expected data are not the same

Comment: @Branson FoxI just want to create a binary variable. It does not matter what it can be called.

Comment: @ akrun. Thanks for noticing that. I would like to consider the later part. The only thing is that I would like to create a variable column "Entire a" based on the previous columns (Monday : Wednesday).

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with dplyr solution:

```
library(dplyr)

my.data <- data.frame(
  age = c("6-9", "6-9", "6-9", "9-10", "9-10", "9-10"),
  Monday = c("a", "b", NA, "c", "a", "a"),
  Tuesday = c("a", "b", "a", "c", "a", NA),
  Wednesday = c("a", "c", "a", "c", "a", NA)
)

my.data %>%
  mutate(
    `Entire a` = apply(.[, 2:4], 1, function(x) all(x == "a", na.rm = T) %>% as.numeric)
  )

# age Monday Tuesday Wednesday Entire a
# 1  6-9      a       a         a        1
# 2  6-9      b       b         c        0
# 3  6-9   <NA>       a         a        1
# 4 9-10      c       c         c        0
# 5 9-10      a       a         a        1
# 6 9-10      a    <NA>      <NA>        1
```

The `na.rm` argument within `all()` function will control whether You will ignore missing values.

Comment: @ Linards. Thank you. For some reason, it is no considering those rows which have only one "a" and the remaining all are missing.

Comment: Could You, please, add an example with the NA cases - the updated example above treats nicely the rows with all but one NA.

Answer (score 0):

We could create a logical matrix with `==` and get the `rowSums` to convert to `binary`

```
colnm <- names(dataframe)[-1]
dataframe$Entire_a <- +(rowSums(replace(dataframe[colnm], 
       dataframe[colnm] == '', 'a') == 'a')  == length(colnm))
dataframe$Entire_a
#[1] 1 0 0 0 1
```

Or another option is to `paste` and then use `grep`

```
+(grepl("^a+$", do.call(paste, c(dataframe[colnm], sep=""))))
#[1] 1 0 0 0 1
```

If the missing value is `NA` and not blank (`''`), then use

```
+(rowSums(replace(dataframe[colnm], is.na(dataframe[colnm]), 'a') == 'a')  == 3)
```

#### data

```
dataframe <- structure(list(Age = c("6-9", "6-9", "6-9", "9-10", "9-10"), 
    Monday = c("a", "b", "", "c", "a"), Tuesday = c("", "b", 
    "c", "c", "a"), Wednesday = c("a", "c", "a", "b", "a")), 
    row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `pmap_int` from `purrr` for this row-wise operation.

Turn empty values (`''`) to `NA` if they are not already.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

dataframe %>%
    na_if('') %>%
    mutate(Entire_a = pmap_int(select(., Monday:Wednesday), 
                         ~+all(c(...) == 'a', na.rm = TRUE)))

#   Age Monday Tuesday Wednesday Entire_a
#1  6-9      a    <NA>         a        1
#2  6-9      b       b         c        0
#3  6-9   <NA>       c         a        0
#4 9-10      c       c         b        0
#5 9-10      a       a         a        1
```

Comment: @ Ronak. Thank you. For some reason, it is no considering those rows which have only one "a" and the remaining all are missing.

Comment: @fitrat It should actually work. Can you give an example using `dput` where it fails?